# Selenium can not find element from workera.ai

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape question answers from workera.ai but I am stuck because Selenium cannot find any element I searched for using class. When I check the page source the element is available but Selenium can not find it. Here is what I am doing.

**Signup using: https://workera.ai/candidates/signup**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time, os

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
option.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
option.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") #e.g. C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
option.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 2') # using profile which is logged into the website
#option.add_argument("--headless")
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
wd = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)
skill_sets = ['https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/82746bf6-4eb2-4065-b2fb-740bc3207d14','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/7553e8f8-52bf-4136-a4ea-6aa63eb963d9','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/e11cb698-38c1-4a4f-aa7b-43b85bdf5a51','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/a999048c-ab99-4576-b849-4e72c9455418','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/7df84ad9-ae67-4faf-a981-a95c1c02adbb', 'https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/737fa250-8c66-4ea0-810b-6847c304aa5b','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/ed4f2f1f-2333-4b28-b36a-c7f736da9647','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/323ba5d9-fffe-48c0-b7b4-966d1ebca99a','https://workera.ai/app/learner/skillset/488492e9-53c4-4600-b336-6dfe44340402']
#                                             AI fluent                                                                       AI literate                                                                       DATA ANAlyst                                                           DATA Engineer                                                                        DATA scientist                                                                        Deep learn                                                                  ML                                                                           Responsible AI                                                                   Software Engineer
for skill in skill_sets:
    wd.get(skill)
    time.sleep(20)
    num = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sc-jNHgKk hrMhpT")# class name is different for every account
    num = num.split('of')[1]
    num = int(num)
    print(num)
    button = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "styled__SBase-sc-cmjz60-0 styled__SPrimary-sc-cmjz60-1 kSmXiJ hwoYMb sc-fKVqWL eOjNfz")
    print(len(button))
wd.close()
```

I don't know why it is happening. Does the site block Selenium web drivers or it is something else?

### Edit

I tried getting page source from Selenium and then accessing elements using bs4 and it is working. So I think the website is blocking Selenium by some mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with selenium is that you can't select elements that has **more than one class** like this.

In order to select them, you can either mention one class in the value, or use "."
for example:

```
wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"class1.class2")
```

Also you can select the class that exists for all the answers which I believe it is this one "sc-jNHgKk", so you won't have the problem to select a class for each account, or you can just use XPATH instead.

```
num = int(wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sc-jNHgKk").text.split("of ")[1])
button = wd.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "styled__SBase-sc-cmjz60-0")
print(len(button))
```